# How to append slice to byte array in golang

Tags: go, slice

I try to pass dynamic slic to this jsonstr slice

```
var catlist []string
var jsonStr = []byte(`{"categoryList":`+catlist+`}`)
```

But i'm getting this error

```
 invalid operation: "{\"categoryList\":" + catlist (mismatched types string and []string)
```

How can I fix this error

Comment: Why do you want to construct JSON manually?  Use struct or `map[string]interface{}`. Take a look at [https://blog.golang.org/json-and-go](https://blog.golang.org/json-and-go)

Comment: This is not the idomatic way of doing json in golang. Here is some examples : https://gobyexample.com/json

Answer (score -1):

You are concating `string` and `[]string`!! this is impossible!
You must use `json` package:
[Package json](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/)

Answer (score -2):

```
data := make(map[string]interface{})
        data["categoryList"] = catlist
        bytearray, err := json.Marshal(data)
        req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(bytearray))
```